# Compare every nth line in 2 files and save (asymmetric) context

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, diff, file-comparison

I have 2 files, each containing the same amount of 4-lines records, in the same order:

`fileA`:

```
record1 line1=header
record1 line2 X <= this is different but should be ignored
record1 line3 id ABC
record1 line4
record2 line1=header
record2 line2
record2 line3 id DEF <= this is different
record2 line4
```

`fileB`:

```
record1 line1=header
record1 line2 Y <= this is different but should be ignored
record1 line3 id ABC
record1 line4
record2 line1=header
record2 line2
record2 line3 id GHI <= this is different
record2 line4
```

For each record, I want to compare its `line3` between 2 files and if `line3` are different, save the whole record (lines1-4) of fileB; in the example above, record1 will be ignored and record2 saved. 
I have basic knowledge of `diff` and not sure if it is doable at all. First, I don't know how to compare only every 3rd line and ignore the others; second, `-C` defines *symmetrical* context, i.e. equal number of lines before and after the difference...

**UPD**. Initially I had a mistake in my examples: blank line between records which I don't have in my real files. I apologize for this.
Based on @stteldriver's answer, I have the following solution:

```
awk '
NR%4==3 {
lineA3=$0; 
getline lineB1 < "fileB"; 
getline lineB2 < "fileB"; 
getline lineB3 < "fileB"; 
getline lineB4 < "fileB";  
if (lineA3 != lineB3) {printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", lineB1,lineB2,lineB3,lineB4;}
}' fileA
```

It works perfectly! Though the code is quite ugly (I'm only starting to learn `awk`!), will be grateful if you can optimize it.

Comment: Your updated code above is sound, although uniquely tailored to your two input file format. You could perhaps simplify it a bit, but it is more a matter of style. The last test could be written: `lineA3 != lineB3 && {printf "%s\n%", lineB1,lineB2,lineB3,lineB4}` As you can see the `if (...)` construct is implicit and the `printf` method uses the same format and applies it to any input fed to it until exhausted. --- Steeldriver's array-based code is fine of course, although more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your updated input, based strictly on 4-line records, you can use modulo arithmetic to maintain arrays of the current records, and check the 3rd lines for a match every 4th line:

```
$ awk '
    {a[FNR%4] = $0; getline b[FNR%4] < "fileB"} 
    !(FNR%4) && b[3] != a[3] {
      for(i=0;i<4;i++) print b[i%4]
    }
  ' fileA
record2 line1=header
record2 line2
record2 line3 id GHI <= this is different
record2 line4
```

(note that one really should check the return value of the `getline` command, and do something sensible if it fails).

---

For your originally-posted input, you could have used *paragraph mode*:

```
$ awk -vRS= -F'\n' '{A3 = $3}; getline "fileB" > -1 && $3 != A3' fileA
record2 line1=header
record2 line2
record2 line3 id DEF <= this is different
record2 line4
```

The empty `RS` causes whole blank-line separated records to be read, for both normal processing (input from `fileA`) and for `getline` (input from `fileB`). Setting the field separator to newline (`\n`) then allows us to save the whole line `$3` from one and compare to the other. If they are not equal, the default print outputs `$0` (which is the whole record from the `getline` of `fileB`).

Comment: thanks a lot @steeldriver! I'm so sorry, I made a mistake in my example: in fact my records are not separated by blank lines, it goes continuously 4-4-4-4... Do you have any idea for the solution that would be based only on the line number? (but in any case please don't delete the current solution: I learned a lot from it). I apologize again for the confusion.

Comment: @VasilyA I have added a different approach for your updated case

Comment: awesome, thanks! (I can't say I understand completely how it works :) but it works)

Comment: why `print b[i%4]` instead of just `print b[i]` ?

Comment: @Cbhihe because the arrays are constructed using `FNR%4`, `line4` becomes `b[0]` - using `b[i%4]` in the print statement ensures the lines of the record are output in the correct order (1,2,3,0).

Comment: Gotcha ! It had escaped me completely. Clever.

Comment: @Cbhihe tbh I missed it the first time around - didn't notice the output was in the wrong order until after I posted the answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Python script that should do what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""compare.py"""

import sys

file_A = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
file_B = open(sys.argv[2], "r")

records_A = file_A.read().split("\n\n")
records_B = file_B.read().split("\n\n")

for record_A, record_B in zip(records_A, records_B):
    lines_A = record_A.split("\n")
    lines_B = record_B.split("\n")
    if lines_A[2] != lines_B[2]:
        print("{}\n".format(record_B))
```

You would run it like this:

```bsh
python compare.py fileA fileB
```

When I run it on your example data, I get the desired output:

```
record2 line1=header
record2 line2
record2 line3 id GHI <= this is different
record2 line4
```

Comment: thank you @igal, I really appreciate the input! Ideally, I wanted some sort of shell-only based solution, `awk` is closer to that. But maybe your solution will work faster for the big files I have... I will make a benchmark and add a comment about it.